# Anypoint CloudHub 2.0 app vs CloudHub app

Tags: cloudhub, anypoint-platform

We have an app in CloudHub 1.0 running successfully in which we are importing data from Salesforce to our local datawarehouse everyday, now we are trying to deploy the same app using CloudHub 2.0, (with a different name), app deploys successfully but it is not establishing connection with our datawarehouse failing with the error below, we have same app confirguration and app properties on CloudHub and CloudHub 2.0:

Message               : Cannot get connection for URL jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER IPADDRESS:1434;databaseName=ABC: The TCP/IP connection to the host , port *** has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
Element               : AccountsFlowBatch/processors/0 @ sfcomdw2:sfcomdw.xml:1340 (Delete)
Element DSL           : <db:delete doc:name="Delete" doc:id="f3cdca26-ba9f-412e-afa1-53e035f20ae4" config-ref="Database_Config">
<db:sql><![CDATA[

DELETE [Database].[ABC].[SF_AccountDaily]

]]></db:sql>
</db:delete>
Error type            : DB:CONNECTIVITY

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a networking issue. You haven't provided any details about the network configuration but from the reference to an IP address I'm guessing there is some network link between the CloudHub 1.0 deployment and your private network. For example an Anypoint VPN is established. Read the [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/cloudhub-2/ps-setup). You should verify that the same network link is compatible with your CloudHub 2.0 private space and is applied too.

You may need your Anypoint Platform administrator and your networking team to assist.